# There has to be an easier way.. pulling data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I need to pull 3 values from a table and assign each one to a variable
each value is based on to columns, a type and an id

```
$ht_live_query = mysql_query("SELECT htcode FROM coupon WHERE pid='$pid' AND type='L'");
$ht_live_result = mysql_fetch_array($ht_live_query);
$htCODE_Live = $ht_live_result['htcode'];
```

> You can see that I am assigning the desired value to the variable $htL

```
$ht_General_query = mysql_query("SELECT htcode FROM coupon WHERE pid='$pid' AND type='G'");
$ht_General_result = mysql_fetch_array($ht_General_query);
$htCODE_General = $ht_General_result['htcode'];

$ht_Reward_query = mysql_query("SELECT htcode FROM coupon WHERE pid='$pid' AND type='R'");
$ht_Reward_result = mysql_fetch_array($ht_Reward_query);
$htCODE_Reward = $ht_Reward_result ['htcode'];
```

I know I am doing this the hard way but can not figure out how to do the foreach or while loop to attain the desired results.

Comment: FYI... naming your variables to be something clear really helps other people understand your code quickly (including yourself when you revisit code you've written in the past). If people understand it quicker, then they'll be more willing to help you. :-)

Comment: Advice taken, I hope that looks better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `IN()` clause as `IN('L','G','R')`.

```
$htrrquery = mysql_query("SELECT htcode, type FROM coupon WHERE pid='$pid' AND type IN('L','G','R')");
```

When fetching results, you can check the value and do something different if necessary.

```
while ($row = mysql_fecth_array($htrrquery)) {
  echo = $row['htcode'];
  switch ($row['type']) {
    case 'L': $htL = $row['htcode']; break;
    case 'G': $htG = $row['htcode']; break;
    case 'R': $htR = $row['htcode']; break;
  }
}
```

Comment: @AdamWenger it will if he tests the value of `htcode` in the loop... See addition

Comment: do i loop through this or just fetch array and assign variables [L} [G]? sorry but I have never used IN

Comment: @DanielHunter see my update. You can use a switch inside the loop. Also note that I added `type` to your select list. You use the value of `type` to determine which other variable to populate with `htcode`.

Comment: I like this solution better because this handles the case where not all three values are found.

Comment: Perfect.. This is so clean. +10 if I could. Thank You! cant accept the answer for 3 min ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$htlquery = mysql_query("SELECT htcode FROM coupon WHERE pid='$pid' 
                         AND type IN 'G','L','R') ORDER BY type");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($htlquery)) {  // EDIT: added loop
    $return[] = $row[0];
}

list($htG, $htL, $htR)  = $return;
```

Comment: The above code though will break if all three rows aren't returned.

Comment: Only one column `htcode` is being selected here. Where do you expect to get three values into `list()` without a loop?

Comment: I'm using php's `list()` feature - http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php  If the query returns three rows then `list()` will assign them to those three variables.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` only returns one row at a time.  Each row has only one column, so you cannot fill three variables into `list()`  To retrieve three rows, `mysql_fetch_array()` must be called three times.

Comment: @Michael Ah gotcha +1.  For some reason I assumed it returned all three rows.  Will edit in a sec.